# Group items by 3 in for each loop

Tags: php, html, css

I have an array of items and want to loop through them but instead of grouping them inside of a div I would like to group them by css Class.

I dont want to do div grouping because of mobile views there might be 4 or more in line and the breaks css class will change as the screen size changes or will be moved to absolute positioning removing the break all together and forming a grid.

I can create the breaks every 3 items but the class assign im struggling with.

Any help would be appreciated.

I would like to create the below layout in a PHP foreach loop.

ex.

```
<div class="listing">
   <div class="group_1">item1</div>
   <div class="group_1">item2</div>
   <div class="group_1">item3</div>

   <div class="break_1"></div>

   <div class="group_2">item4</div>
   <div class="group_2">item5</div>
   <div class="group_2">item6</div>

   <div class="break_2"></div>

   <div class="group_3">item7</div>
   <div class="group_3">item8</div>
   <div class="group_3">item9</div>

   <div class="break_3"></div>

   <div class="group_4">item10</div>
   <div class="group_4">item11</div>
   <div class="group_4">item12</div>

   <div class="break_4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the real question?
Is about the CSS undefined number of different class groups?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your php code

Comment: Ive tried loads of loops but nothing works, i will add some code now to clear up a few things.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, is your problem in generating the output with PHP? If so: 1. Create indexing variable (i=0). 2. On each iteration check the result of ((int) (i/3))+1. Concatenate "group_" with the result and you will get your class name. 3. On the end of the iteration increment i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very sure if it is what you are looking, anyway, given a basic array like this:

`$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);`

you can loop it and have the code you expect this way:

```
$group_num=1;
echo "<div class='listing'>";
foreach ($arr as $key=>$item) {

    echo "<div class='group_$group_num'>$item</div>";
    if ($key%3==0) {
        echo "<div class='break'></div>";
        $group_num++;
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

Results:

```
<div class='listing'>
<div class='group_1'>1</div>
<div class='group_1'>2</div>
<div class='group_1'>3</div>

<div class='break'></div>

<div class='group_2'>4</div>    
<div class='group_2'>5</div>    
<div class='group_2'>6</div>

<div class='break'></div>

<div class='group_3'>7</div>
<div class='group_3'>8</div>
<div class='group_3'>9</div>

<div class='break'></div>

<div class='group_4'>10</div>
<div class='group_4'>11</div>
<div class='group_4'>12</div>

<div class='break'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also exactly what i was looking for. This is a bit closer to what i was looking for and neat so accepting this as the correct answer.

Comment: this won't work if you only have two items or items not divisible by 3. We should get the remainder grouped two, if for example the last group has 2 items then they should be grouped but in this case they will not sine the modulus of  $x divide by 3 is not zero

Answer (score 2):

if we have array of items as :

```
$items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8'];

$result = '';

foreach($items as $index => $item) {
    $groupNumber = intval(floor($index/3)) + 1;
    $result .= "<div class='group_$groupNumber'>$item</div>";
}
echo $result;
```

and this is a sample output

[image]

Comment: I fixed an error I forgot about indexes, I fixed the code
try it now

Comment: Thank you, This is perfect. Exactly what i had in mind, i have already made the adjustments you did. Once i saw your code it all came to me. Ive been working too much lately i think! Will accept answer in a min.

Comment: sure bro, thank you @JohanPretorius
I added a screenshot for the result
and the code now 100% working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Giacomo Pittalis and Hassan Ali Salem I have managed to solve this in a bit of a crude way.

```
<?php
    $items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9', 'item10'];
    $i = 0;
    $len = count($items);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $mod = intval(floor($i / 3) + 1);

        echo '<div class="' . 'group_' . $mod . '">' . $items[$i] . '</div>';

        if (($i % 3 == 2)) { ?>
            <div class="content_holder hidden" id="group_<?php echo $mod; ?>"></div>
        <?php }

        if ($i == $len - 1) { ?>
            <div class="content_holder hidden" id="group_<?php echo $mod; ?>"></div>
        <?php }
        $i++;
    }
?>
```